# Why do I get a "Can't pickle ..." when I try to run a function and kill it if it timeouts?

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout

first of all let me tell you I'm kind of a newb at threads and multiprocessing.

I've got a Python graphical program that once you choose a translation site and click a button, calls a thread to open up a browser and do a search on that given site (I'm using splinter, which uses selenium, and qt for the graphical part) of the terms located in a text file selected by the user.

I'm trying to timeout the search of each term on the site to 30 seconds, because sometimes there are loading problems, or other issues, and I want to be able to skip the term if it takes to time to search and try at a later time.

So:
I have this code on the event handler of the button:

```
self.searchThread = PesquisaThread()
self.searchThread.start()
```

Then at the run method of the thread I have:

```
glossary.do_search(0, site_to_look_for)
```

'glossary' is the class of the gui.

Then if the glossary translib is selected 'do_search' does:

```
search_translib(language_from,language_to)
```

Which then calls for the function that does the opening of the browser and clicking of the links, etc, like so...

```
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=search_term_language,args=(browser,'Portuguese', row, column,termo_unicode))
p.start()
p.join(30)
```

But when this particular code runs I get:

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle '_subprocess_handle' object: <_subprocess_handle object at 0x0230DA60>
```

I'm at a loss, does anyone know what is going on.

Thank you
Daniel

Comment: multiprocessing tries to pickle all of the args to send to the child process. I'm not sure what 'browser' is, but if its the selenium browser or something like that, its a huge unpicklable object that shouldn't be sent w/ multiprocessing. Try sending just the data and doing the browser stuff in the child.

Comment: I'll try that when I get back to work, will report then, thanks for commenting

Comment: That was the problem, thanks for helping!!